# Swap string parts (with code) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a lot of strings like:

```
str_replace($arr[15], "p", $this->Text->text);
```

(**NOTE:** instead or $arr[15] can be any number, like $arr[92])

(**NOTE:** instead or "p" can be any letter *or* number, like "c" or "1")

and how do I turn it to like:

```
str_replace("p", $arr[15], $this-Text->text);
```

as I said above, there can be any letter or number (because I have a lot of strings like that).

If anybody can, help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note questions should be questions, answers should be answers. See [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) If you want to share your solution, just write an answer. Another thing: the question is solved when any answer is accepted; there's no need to put "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `str_replace\(\K(\$arr\[\d+\])(,\h*)("\w")`
- Replace with: `$3$2$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
str_replace\(   # literally
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(               # start group 1
  \$arr\[       # literally $arr[
  \d+           # 1 or more digits
  \]            # closing square bracket
)               # end group 2
(,\h*)          # group 2, a comma followed by 0 or more horizontal spaces
("\w")          # group 3, a word character inside double quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3          # content of group 3
$2          # content of group 2
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]